# Generating a sequence where the gap between numbers increases

Tags: r, matrix, seq

I need to generate a sequence on R where the gap between elements increases each time

Seq1:

## 1, 49, 100, 154, ... 19306

Seq2:

## 48, 99, 153, 210, ..., 19650

Note the gap between seq1 elements increases by 3 each time. 49-1 = 48, 100-49 =51, 154-100 = 54...

The gap between Seq2 elements also increases by 3 each time 99-48 =51, 153-99 = 54

Comment: Use seq to generate a vector of the differences and then use that with cumsum

Answer (score 0):

Given the advice from @Dason:

```
seq1 <- seq(48, 19306,3)
which(cumsum(seq1) ==19650)
seq2 <- cumsum(seq1)[1:100]

seq3 <- seq(47, 19306, 3)
seq4 <- seq2 -seq3[1:100]
```